# Mongoose times out if databasename is set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm rather new to Linux, NodeJs and MongoDB but I setup a Linux Server running a MongoDB (db version v4.0.16).

I added two users like this. One called mongo-admin and one called mongo-root.

```
# mongo

> use admin
> db.createUser({ 
    user: "mongo-admin", 
    pwd: "myAwesomePassword", 
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] 
})

> db.createUser({ 
    user: "mongo-root", 
    pwd: "myAwesomePassword", 
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ] 
})
```

I then enabled authentication in /etc/mongod.conf like this

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

On my development Machine I setup a little NodeJS script that tries to connect to the server using mongoose, and simply add a document there.

Now the situation is very strange. If I use `mongodb://mongo-root:myAwesomePassword@100.100.100.100:27017` as a connectionstring, everything works fine and a new DB named `test` is created and the document is added. But as soon as I add a `/mydatabasename` at the end of the string, mongoose will suddntly time out after 30 seconds of trying to connect.

If I connect to MongoDB using a Software called Robo3T, I can connect just fine, and I also have the rights to create a new database just fine.

I also checked the `/etc/log/mongod.log` and found this error:

```
2020-02-05T07:40:22.006+0000 I ACCESS   [conn27] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for mongo-root on mydatabasename from client 101.101.101.101:51270 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user mongo-admin@mydatabasename
```

This is the way I connect to the DB

```
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://mongo-root:myAwesomePassword@100.100.100.100:27017/mydatabasename",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
  }
);
```

It seems like mongodb is looking for the user in the database that should be created instead of in the admin db.

Comment: Are you using mongodb Atlas ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what that is. On my Linux Server I installed the MongoDB Community Edition. I'm not dependent on any other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html)

```
 mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[database][?options]]
```

> **/database**
>
> Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the connection
>   string includes authentication credentials in the form of
>   username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection
>   string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin
>   database. See also authSource.
>
> **authSource**
>
> Specify the database name associated with the user’s credentials.
>   **authSource defaults to the database specified in the connection
>   string**.

Actually the documentation is not 100% correct for this point, the connection string must be like this:

```
mongodb://mongo-root:myAwesomePassword@100.100.100.100:27017/mydatabasename?authSource=admin
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This did the trick. I was looking into the mongoose documentation where the connection string was not explained as detailed.